# Difference between a transformation being split and diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

I just learned the definition of a split transformation today and it seems very similar to the condition for a transformation to be diagonalizable. It's probably obvious, but I just want to make sure I'm parsing it correctly.

So a diagonalizable transformation is split but a split transformation is not necessarily diagonalizable. Correct?

Comment: What is a "split transformation" and from where did you get the definition?

Comment: @DonAntonio I got the definition from a Lie Algebra textbook written by my professor. It reads, "The linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow V$ is a split transformation if the minimum polynomial $p(t)$ splits into linear factors over the field $F$. Is this not a common term/definition? I may be mistaken, but a transformation's minimum polynomial has to have distinct linear factors to be diagonalizable, from which I deduced the above implications.

Comment: Ok, then you're right: a matrix is diagonalizable (over some given field) iff its minimal polynomial splits in *different* linear factors (or, equivalently, if it splits in linear factors and all its roots are simple), but according to what you say this is *not* the same as a "split transformation" as  the linear factors of the min. pol. can be multiple...

Comment: @DonAntonio Okay, thank you for your confirmation. Is there a different meaning to "split transformation" that's more common? I figure the quotation marks referenced the definition I gave, but not necessarily the term in general.

Comment: I had never known of "split transformation", that's why I asked. There're several examples of split things in mathematics that I know of (short exact sequences, field extensions, polynomials, etc.), but tansformation I never heard of.

Comment: This is equivalent to the matrix/operator being triangularizable.

Answer (score 1):

I understand 'split' to mean that all the eigenvalues of T lie in the field F.  Thus T can be represented by a matrix in Jordan form over F, i.e. T = D + N where D (diagonalisable) and N (nilpotent) are both K-linear maps of V.  This is certainly equivalent to the minimal polynomial of T splitting into linear factors over F, since its roots are the eigenvalues of T.

Answer (score 0):

When you say split what exactly do you mean?  A diagonal matrix which gives either an injection or a surjection is an isomorphism, so it's trivially split (it has an inverse).  But not all diagonal matrices give injective or surjective maps so it's not clear what you would mean by split.

Comment: This, more than an answer, seems to be a comment...